# Google analytics numbers for a Shiny visualistion in an iframe are way less than the parent page

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, iframe

I have a few Shiny apps visualization which is are hosted on Shinyapps.io which is then embedded on my website in an iframe.

We have quite a few of these apps that we use on the website and we have been going through a lot of them and checking the numbers and quite a few are quite low in comparison to the page that they are embedded in.

For one example the page views for the website page that the app is embedded in is around 9000 for the last 3 months, where the Shiny app is only showing 600 for the same time period. When you access the page the visualization seems to load quickly, and we use for quite a few other apps.

I have seperate Google Analytics properties for all the Shiny apps as well as a seperate account for the website. These are on completely different domains and not linked.

Things I have checked

- Tag Manager installed correctly and single instance
- Analytics installation - checked for extra tracking codes etc
- Checked all the filters but the raw views have the same issue
- Timed loading of the Application

Any ideas/suggestion on what might be causing this that I can use to debug this issue would be greatly apreciated.